# laravel eloquent search many to many Relashionship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I use eloquent for my app and Laravel Livewire for instant searches in my models

My school model

```
public function filieres ()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Filiere','etablissement_filieres',
    'id_etablissements','id_filieres')->withPivot('prise_en_charge', 'prix');
}
```

My faculty model

```
public function etablissements ()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Etablissement','etablissement_filieres',
    'id_etablissements','id_filieres',)->withPivot('prise_en_charge', 'prix');
}
```

I got all the faculties of each school with

```
@foreach($school as $etablissement)
                @foreach($etablissement->filieres as $filiere)
                  <div class="container bg-white my-4 py-4">
                    <div class="row pl-5">
                      <div class="col-md-9">
                        <h5 class="font-weight-bold">{{ $filiere ->nom}} </h5><a href="{{ route('etablissement.show', ['etablissement' => $etablissement->id]) }}" target="_blank">
                        <h6 class="font-weight-bold mt-n1">{{ $etablissement ->nom}}</a></h6>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-3 pt-n5">
                        <img src="{{ asset($etablissement->logo) }}" alt="">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row pl-5 mt-md-n5">
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h6> <strong> Diplôme de fin cycle</strong>: {{ $filiere ->diplome_obtenu}} <br>
                        <strong>Diplôme requis</strong>: {{ $filiere ->diplome_requis}} <br>
                        <strong>Durée</strong>: {{ $filiere ->duree}}<br>
                        <strong>Montant de la formation</strong>: {{ $filiere->pivot->prix}}</h6>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h6> <strong> Mode d'etude</strong>: {{ $filiere ->type}} <br>
                        <strong>Prise en charge</strong>: {{ $filiere->pivot->prise_en_charge}}</h6>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row pl-5 mt-4">
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <a href="{{ route('etablissement.show', ['etablissement' => $etablissement->id]) }}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary font-weight-bold btn-sm orange w-75 now">DETAILS DE L'UNIVERSITE</a>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <a href="{{ asset($etablissement->brochure) }}" class="btn btn-primary font-weight-bold btn-sm green w-75 now">TELECHARGER LA BROCHURE</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  @endforeach
                    @endforeach
```

Everything works. but i want to search for faculties or schools only through instant search box so i tried this

```
public $query;

public function render()
{
    return view('livewire.etablissement-list', [
        'school' => Etablissement::where('nom', 'like', '%'. $this->query . '%')->orWhereHas('filieres', function($q){
            $q->where('nom', 'LIKE', '%' . $this->query . '%');
        })->with('filieres')->paginate(4),
    ]);
}
```

But when I search for "finances" for example, it brings me back all the faculties of the school whose name is associated with a school.
I only want him to bring me only the faculty or faculties corresponding to this research... Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is `with` query because `with` will produce another query. so `orWhereHas('filieres')` replaced by `with('filieres')` query.

solution

```
$filieresConstrain = function($q) {
   $q->where('nom', 'LIKE', '%' . $this->query . '%');
};

->orWhereHas('filieres', $filieresConstrain)
->with(['filieres' => $filieresConstrain]);
```

Comment: it does not work, it brings nothing when I do a search

Comment: sorry I was wrong in my variable. it works